# How to put vertical text in an equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-alignment

I want to put vertical text in my equation, like in this example:

[image: vertical]

I got

```
\begin{equation}
    Dir(\alpha) \xrightarrow{iid} 
\end{equation}
```

and tried to put in linebreaks, but that does not work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
\begin{equation}
    Dir(\alpha)\xrightarrow{iid}
    \begin{matrix}
    q^{(1)}\\
    q^{(2)}\\
    \vdots\\
    q^{(L)}
    \end{matrix},
\end{equation}
```

That said, you should also put `\DeclareMathOperator{\Dir}{Dir}` in your preamble and use `\Dir` instead of writing `Dir` directly.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the spacing gap between the items of the stack to be customized, you can use this approach.  The inter-item  gap is set by the second argument to the `\setstackgap` macro.  Two examples shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\stackMath
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\parskip 2em
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{S}{9pt}
\begin{equation}
    Dir(\alpha)\xrightarrow{iid}
   \sbox{\tempbox}{\Shortstack[l]{%
    q^{(1)}\\
    q^{(2)}\\
    \vdots\\
    q^{(L)}
    }}%
    \abovebaseline[-.5\ht\tempbox+.5\ht\strutbox]{\usebox{\tempbox}},
\end{equation}

\setstackgap{S}{1pt}
\begin{equation}
    Dir(\alpha)\xrightarrow{iid}
   \sbox{\tempbox}{\Shortstack[l]{%
    q^{(1)}\\
    q^{(2)}\\
    \vdots\\
    q^{(L)}
    }}%
    \abovebaseline[-.5\ht\tempbox+.5\ht\strutbox]{\usebox{\tempbox}},
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]